# comparing values in a php array with values from a form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I've been working on a small website which reads data from a form and then compares it to data on a file. The data on the file is stored in a series of arrays, and then compared to the data from the form. If there is a match between the data from the form and data in the first array, a value is returned, if not, another value is returned instead

```
<?php
$file = fopen("Student.txt", "a+") or exit("Unable to open file!");
$StudentID = array();
$StudentPassword = array();
$StudentFname = array();
$StudentLname = array();
$StudentDOB = array();
$StudentGPA = array();
$x = 0;
$return = 0;
while(!feof($file))
  {
  $StudentID[$x] = fgets($file). "<br>";
  $StudentPassword[$x] = fgets($file). "<br>";
  $StudentFname[$x] = fgets($file). "<br>";
  $StudentLname[$x] = fgets($file). "<br>";
  $StudentDOB[$x] = fgets($file). "<br>";
  $StudentGPA[$x] = fgets($file). "<br>";
  $x = $x + 1;
  }

  $ID = $_POST["StudentID"];
  $Pass = $_POST["StudentPass"];
  $First = $_POST["StudentFname"];
  $last = $_POST["StudentLname"];
  $DOB = $_POST["D.O.B."];
  $GPA = $_POST["GPA"];

  for ($y=0; $y<$x; $y++){
      if (strcmp($ID,$StudentID[$y]) != 0){
         $return = 1;
         echo "duplicate found";
         $y = $x;
      }
      else{
          $return = 2;
      }
  }
  echo "<br>";
  echo $return;
fclose($file);
?>
```

however, regardless of the data from the file, it always output the value that one would get if the data is the same.  The two data values being compared is the ID value from the post, named $ID, and the array of values $StudentID

the form which the data is obtained from is this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-Transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
     <title>Student Addition</title>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" 
        content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ExternalCss3.css"/>
</head>

    <script>
    function validateForm()
{
var a=document.forms["my_form"]["StudentID"].value;
var b=document.forms["my_form"]["StudentPass"].value;
var c=document.forms["my_form"]["StudentFname"].value;
var d=document.forms["my_form"]["StudentLname"].value;
var e=document.forms["my_form"]["D.O.B."].value;
var f=document.forms["my_form"]["GPA"].value;
if (a==null || a=="")
  {
  alert("ID must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
  if (b==null || b=="")
  {
  alert("password must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
  if (c==null || c=="")
  {
  alert("First Name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
  if (d==null || d=="")
  {
  alert("Last Name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
    if (e==null || e=="")
  {
  alert("Date of Birth must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
    if (f==null || f=="")
  {
  alert("GPA must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>

<body>
    <Table class = "dataform" Border = "0" WIDTH = "325">
    <TR>
    <TD COLSPAN = "2">
    <form action = "ConfirmStudentAdd.php" method="post" name="my_form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        Student ID: <input type="text" name="StudentID"><br>
        Student Password: <input type="password" name="StudentPass"><br>
        Student First Name <input type="text" name="StudentFname"><br>
        Student Last Name <input type="text" name="StudentLname"><br>
        Student D.O.B. <input type="text" name="D.O.B."><br>
        Student GPA <input type="text" name="GPA"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
    </form>
    <TD>
    </TR>
    </Table>
    <p class = "Login">
    <img src = "UWITStudentAddLogo.png" alt="Student Addition"/>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

the data submits without an issue, its the php code where the problem lies. Any help possible would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you set `$y = $x;`? If you just want to end the loop, use `break;`

Comment: So you have a file of values and you want to search it for a specific set?

Comment: I'll fix the $y = $x part, and, its not exactly a file of values

step 1: file of values is read by the php code and placed into 6 arrays

step 2: the values from the form are taken and placed into 6 variables

step 3: the 1st value from the form is compared to the 1st array from the file read; if a match is found, the loop breaks, and the value 1 is returned, if not, the value is set to 2, and the loop continues until a match is found or there are no more values to compare

problem is, no matter what the values are, the value 1, the value for a match found, is returned

Comment: Why are you concatenating `<br>` when you fill in the arrays? That's not likely to be in the posted values and is probably causing the comparisons to fail. BTW, your loop is basically equivalent to `in_array($ID, $StudentID)`.

Comment: I removed the <br> concatenating from the code that adds the file data to the array, but still no luck. I'll try in_array function and see if that works Edit: using the function in_array, but the problem persists. This time, regardless of the values compared, it returns the value one gets if a match is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, what you are doing looks sound based on the PHP man page https://www.php.net/strcmp

I would recommend you insert this into your for loop and have a closer look at the output.

```
echo 'id: ' . $ID. ' Student: ' . $studentID[$y] . ' Comp: ' . strcmp($ID,$StudentID[$y]);
```

You'll probably find that the data going in to the loop isn't what you expect.

Comment: I tried it, and it seems that even after reading the data, the array $StudentID is empty....this is a new issue

Comment: what's more confusing, is I had a similar function which read the data from the file and outputed the data in the array. It worked without flaws, and this code is almost literally the same, but the function posted prints out no value for $StudentID

Comment: May as well then do something similar for your loop while(!feof($file)).

Do an echo fgets($file) inside the while loop and see what happens.  Maybe also print_r on each of your arrays after the loop and investigate what has been written to them.

Comment: I got the compare error fixed. turns out that the value returned when both values are the same isn't 0, its -2. I changed the values, and now it can tell the difference between 2 data entries. Thanks!